# Django ValidationError not being raised; key not present in cleaned_data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I have the following form fields on a `ModelForm` subclass:

**forms.py**

```
class ProjectUpdateForm(ModelForm):

    start_date = DateField(...)
    due_date = DateField(label="Due Date",
                         required=True,
                         widget=CustomDatePicker(),
                         validators=[validate_not_past])

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()    # Problem: this isn't this raising a ValidationError...
        start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('start_date')
        due_date = self.cleaned_data.get('due_date')
        if start_date > due_date:          # ...instead getting a TypeError from this line!
            raise ValidationError("Project Start Date cannot be after Project End Date")
```

**validators.py**

```
def validate_not_past(value):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    if value and value < today:
        raise ValidationError('This date cannot be in the past.', code='invalid')
```

Anytime that I enter a date in the past, the applications throws a `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'NoneType'` (see comments above for clarity).

After attempting to troubleshoot, the POST data comes in fine from the form.  The problem occurs because `run_validators()` is raising the `ValidationError` triggered by the `validate_not_past`, validator (above) as expected.  However, rather than raising the `ValidationError`, the `self.cleaned_data` dictionary just doesn't get a `due_date` key.

**I can't figure out why I'm not getting a `ValidationError` raised. I can't find code elsewhere that catches it.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `clean_method` can [ideally optionally return a dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) (recommended) to return the `cleaned_data`. If you do this and are doing inheritance in Forms, you'll not face any errors. Currently, your `ProjectUpdateForm` is not utilizing it correctly to call the `clean()` method on the super-class. Your code will be fixed if you call it correctly like this:

```
class ProjectUpdateForm(ModelForm):

    start_date = DateField(...)
    due_date = DateField(label="Due Date",
                         required=True,
                         widget=CustomDatePicker(),
                         validators=[validate_not_past])

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')
        due_date = cleaned_data.get('due_date')
        if start_date and due_date and start_date > due_date:
            raise ValidationError("Project Start Date cannot be after Project End Date")
        return cleaned_data
```

Note here that I'm also checking `start_date` and `due_date` are not `None` before doing the comparison between them. It wasn't evident from your code if the `start_date` is also mandatory, so I added this additional check.

Finally, I'm also returning `cleaned_data` which is optional but recommended, since then it enables this form to be inherited in other forms without any worries of correctly propagating errors from the super-class forms.